# Hypothesis testing on proportions if $H_0: p = 0$

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

A new medical procedure is tested on 225 subjects ; the observed success rate is 8%. The standard test is used in these cases is to test the possibility that the real success rate is actually 0%.

I understand that the sampling distribution of proportions is a normal distribution centered at $p$ and with standard deviation 
$\sqrt{pq / n}$. How does one perform a hypothesis test on a proportion then if one wants to test the hypothesis $p=0$?

Comment: Reject if you observe any successes, otherwise don't?

Comment: I've rephrased my question, added more details.

Comment: A different scenario is where you observe zero cases and want to estimate the confidence interval. Is that relevant to your problem? Otherwise it is hard to argue with @dsaxton

Comment: The sampling distribution proportion doesn't follow a normal distribution under the null hypothesis p=0. One condition to approximate a binomial with a normal is n·p>5, and here n·p=0. In fact, under the null hypothesis sample proportion has a degenerate distribution with 100% probability of getting 0 successes. In test language, if you get any success p-value=0 and otherwise p-value=1. If you get any success, you can be absolutely sure that p is not 0%. @dsaxton 's answer is more concise, but totally true.

Comment: Ordinarily this is not how medical procedures are tested: they must be compared to a *control group.*  Otherwise there is no valid basis to conclude the successes are due to the procedure itself.  Indeed, it's possible (this has happened) that the procedure is worse than doing nothing.  That's why this question doesn't come up in actual applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: as @dsaxton commented, if you observe any success, reject p=0; otherwise don't reject.

Testing $H_0: p = 0$ (or $H_0: p = 1$) is quite different from testing any other value of p, because the null hypothesis $p=0$ means that no success will be produced, never. Therefore, if we observe one success (even if it's just one in billions and billions), we can be absolutely sure that $p$ is different from 0.

When testing any other value of $p$ (let's say $H_0: p = 0.5$) and the null hypothesis is true, different samples can produce different outcomes, usually with a sample proportion near 0.5 and we can discuss how far from 0.5 need it to be to reject that $p$ equals 0.5. However, if the null hypothesis is $H_0: p = 0$ and it's true, all samples will have the same proportion (no successes) and any other proportion sample proportion is impossible under the null hypothesis. Therefore, if we get any other proportion we must reject the null hypothesis.

As a side note, here the usual approximation of binomial with a normal doesn't work, because one of its conditions is $n·p>5$, and here $n·p=0$. Anyway, it's easy to use the binomial, here - in fact so easy that I wouldn't call it random distribution, because it's just $P(0)=1$ and $P(\text{anything different than 0})=0$. With this distribution and using test language, if you don't get any success p-value=1 and if you get one or more successes p-value=0 (therefore rejecting $H_0$ for any signification).

And as a final example, let's imagine we are tossing a [dime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dime_(United_States_coin)). We can count how many times we see the head or Franklin Roosevelt to decide if it's a fair coin and accept it's fair under a range of proportions, but if we see the image of the Queen of England or the coat of arms of Thailand on the coin, we will reject ipso facto that the coin is a dime.